# Injecting scripts through innerHTML: functions vs global

Tags: javascript, eval, innerhtml

I have some HTML structured as follows

```
<script>
function x()
{
 alert('works');
}
</script>

<table>
(...)
</table>

<script>
console.log('autoexec');
</script>
```

I am loading this HTML from a file in a DIV's innerHTML through an XMLHttpRequest.

Upon completion of the request, this is what I do

```
div.innerHTML = request.responseText;    
var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName("script");       
for(var i=0;i<scripts.length;i++) eval(scripts[i].text);
```

The bottom script, containing code outside a function, gets executed.
However the function x() in the top script isn't evaluated and remains unavailable.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: you're probably missing that the function x is declared **but never executed**. add x(); somewhere inside your code, or auto invoke it. However, please, do NOT use eval() : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: No, I know that x() wouldn't be executed. What I am saying is that it's not evaluated. It isn't available, not in the Window namespace nor elsewhere.

Comment: Of course it is unavailable, because you're injecting it through an ajax request. By the time you're calling it the AJAX request cannot be completed yet, therefore you need to call that function in the window context only when the request has finished.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to call the weird evals you're doing to the injected html. On adding new html containing `<script>`, browser evaluates it automatically. However, note that, for example `$(document).ready()` won't fire if nested inside injected html

Comment: No, I am doing the injection when the AJAX request has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Instead of eval(scripts[i].text) I now use  document.head.appendChild(scripts[i]). This both correctly executes the code outside the function AND makes the function available for calling.